# How to refer to the creator of a work?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

So far I thought *von* is equivalent to *by* when it refers to an author / creator of work, but now I'm confused as I saw some text to use *durch*.

How do I properly refer to the creator of a work?

> People were created by God. (Die Menschen sind von Gott geschaffen.) 
>   The book is written by Mark Twain. (Das Buch ist von Mark Twain geschrieben.)
>   The film was directed by Quentin Tarantino. (Der Film wurde durch Quentin Tarantino eingeführt.)

Comment: Your examples are rather bad, in my opinion, both the (presumably) English original and the German tranlslation, particularly the last one. That said, yes _durch_ can be used for _by_ in certain, not all, cases as well.

Comment: "Regie führen", "dirigieren" or "leiten"; these are the German words that are possible translations for "to direct". In your example, "Regie führen" is the right choice.

Comment: @Iris, i think it's retroactive interference.I'm editing my post.Thanks!

Comment: Your third sentence — as already mentioned by Ingmar — is certainly not idiomatic. I assume you've seen a phrase like "durch + [someone] + [verb]" and then made up your example. Technically, the sentence above may even be the correct original German sentence ("einführen" + "durch" is a valid collocation), but you came up with an incorrect translation into English ("einführen" != "to direct"). Here's the thing: the phrase is not wrong per se, but if the context is a book that is written by or a film that is directed by, then you won't go with "durch".

Answer (score 2):

There are certain rules you have to consider when using the passive voice as you did in your examples:

First of all, I don’t know where you read the third example, but it’s certainly wrong. Here it should also be *Der Film wurde von Q. T. geleitet*.

However, there are two main rules that explain when to use either *von* or *durch* :

- If the agent of an action is a person, the *von-phrase* is used
- If the agent of the action is not a person, the *durch-phrase* is used

example:

- Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben
  (the letter is being written by me) → agent of action = person
- Das Haus ist durch den Sturm zerstört worden
  (the house was destroyed by the storm) → agent of action = object

Comment: “Here it should also be *Der Film wurde von Q. T. geleitet*.” Certainly not; you don’t _leiten_ a film in German. _T. führte Regie bei dem Film_, _T. war der Regisseur des Films_ etc.

Comment: My question was actually how we could refer creater of a work? And you by-passed my first example

Comment: @chirlu _Leitung_ as in _Aufnahmeleitung_ used to be used instead of _Regie_ in German movie credits (probably inherited from French-influenced theater jargon). Interestingly, it is never _Leiter_, _Regisseur_ or _geleitet von_ so there is no direct equivalent for English _director_ and _directed by_, although _Regisseur_ and _Regie führen_ are used in other contexts.

Comment: @Crissov: _Spielleiter_ was sometimes used (but is obsolete now); [_Aufnahmeleiter_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erste_Filmaufnahmeleitung) is a different role.

Comment: In most cases I would consider a *creator of a work* as a person, so you always refer to him/her with *von*. For your first example, there is a special rule in german Grammar: if the agent of the action is either a person OR an object, you can use both *von* and *durch*. Taking God as an example, you can't really say, if God is a real person or something else, an object included. Both is possible: Die Menschen wurden durch/von Gott geschaffen.

Comment: TSieksmeier, you should flag @user1474062 so that he/she becomes aware of your comment. Anyway, your comment is possibly even an edit to the answer worth, but this is certainly up to you.

Comment: @Em1 it's not true i become aware of her(@Tsieksmeier) comment,because i saw her comment just now.I think she must wait at least 24 hours to flag a user.On the hand i care all comments and read them thoroughly

Comment: @user1474062 Fair enough. As you've just posted your question and you are likely to return to this post, you'll read it. However, I referred to the notification that you'll get. Suppose I would post a comment here in 3 weeks from now, or in a year or two. The chance that you read it is very low. And to make sure that you will read it, a user can be notified. — Note that when I comment your question (as opposed to this answer), you'll get notified as the owner of the post. So, TSieksmeier is being notified of every comment below her answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use passive voice in your examples? IMHO, both "The letter is being written by me" and "Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben" sound awkward.

> Gott hat den Menschen geschaffen.

or

> Der Mensch wurde von Gott geschaffen.

(Note that this is "god created man" as opposed to "god crated the humans".)

> Mark Twain hat das Buch geschrieben.

or

> Dieses Buch ist von Mark Twain.

or

> Mark Twain ist der Autor dieses Buchs.

and finally

> Tarantino hat bei diesem Film Regie geführt.

or

> Tarantino ist der Regisseur dieses Films.

Comment: Technically, your answer addresses the title of the question. You gave several ways how to refer to the author. That said, OP seems to look for something different, namely what is the right preposition. I'm afraid this is not addressed by your answer.

Comment: @Em1 Yes, I did not want to repeat @T Sieksmeier's answer with all the passive constructions cause I don't think a word for word translation is appropriate here.

Comment: Fair enough. My point was, however, that this is rather a comment. A comment suggesting to avoid passive voice. My reasoning: this doesn't answer the question (assuming I did understand the question).

Comment: Just to explain my edit. I understand the sentence "Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben" as I'm writing it **right now**. And when I am writing a letter, "the letter is being written by me". Rollback if you disagree or when I misunderstood you, but I think Simple Present is the wrong tense in English here.

Comment: @Em1 The edit is good, it makes it sound even more awkward ;-)